# Veneziano amplitude from 3-point constants

Tags: string-theory, conformal-field-theory, correlation-functions

Consider an open bosonic string in the critical dimension at $g_s = 0$ (only the sphere contributes to the string amplitude).

The scattering of 4 tachyons is given by the Veneziano amplitude.

I'm curious if it is possible to derive the same result from summing over the intermediate states of the string. Suppose that $\left| \lambda\right>$ is a basis of coherent vertex operators (with $\lambda$ the generalized index describing multiple continuous degrees of freedom), and suppose that

$$ 1 = \sum_{\lambda} \left| \lambda \right> \left< \lambda \right|. $$

Intuitively, we expect the 4-point function of 4 tachyons to factorize

$$ \mathcal{A}_4(T(p_1), T(p_2), T(p_3), T(p_4)) = \sum_{\lambda} \mathcal{A}_3(T(p_1), T(p_2), C(\lambda)) \cdot \mathcal{A}_3(C(\lambda), T(p_3), T(p_4)). $$

Question: has this construction ever been made precise?

For instance, the equation (3.18) of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.07016) is an explicit expression for $\mathcal{A}_3(T(p_1), T(p_2), C(\lambda))$. However, if we try to sum over $\lambda$ (which corresponds to integration over $d^D \zeta_i$), we'll acquire an infinite-dimensional Gaussian integral. The result therefore depends on the inverse of the square part matrix $\frac{1}{2} M_{rs} \zeta_r \cdot \zeta_s$, and I'm not sure how that inverse $M^{-1}$ can be calculated given that the structure of $M$ is quite complex.

Comment: I'm happy you asked, but for this question you will find a very explicit exact computation in a forthcoming article (should be out in a couple of weeks or a month or so).  Here one needs to work a little harder, in that the coherent states one needs are offshell (because the intermediate states in the Veneziano amplitude can be offshell).  If you are just interested in the imaginary part then the article you cite is sufficient.  (I will include the ref here when it's out.)

Comment: @Wakabaloola sounds great, I'll wait for your publication.

Comment: @Wakabaloola friendly ping – I'm dying of curiosity to see your paper here :)